# License plates in Zootopia

Tags: analysis, reference, zootopia

What do the two license plates in Zootopia stand for?

1. 29THD03 - at the DMV
2. FST NML - at the end of the movie

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. This is probably a date like Dec. 29th 2003 for example, but director Rich Moore has said that there is no hidden meaning in this [twitter reply](https://twitter.com/_rich_moore/status/724334085632446465?lang=en):

   [image: "Q: Been curious for a while, is there any hidden meaning to the license plate 29THD03?" "Richard Moore: Good question! No hidden meaning, just a bunch of numbers & letters that sounded cool together."]

   Who knows? :)
2. Fast Animal, without the vowels

Comment: A hidden meaning could be hidden from the director too. Hundreds of people must have worked on the movie.

Comment: [Earl Hindman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earl_Hindman) (best known as Wilson W. Wilson from Home Improvement) died December 29, 2003 and his voice has also been heard on the Disneyland Railroad since 2002, maybe that's a connection

Comment: @LarsBeck: Is it known what his voice is representing on that?

Comment: @Zaibis According to the [Disney Wiki](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Earl_Hindman) he's the narrator

Comment: @LarsBeck: Is that narrator somewhere to see on the train? If so is it an anthropomorphic being? That would even strengthen your guess, since that would fit with the "fast animal" part then, and if thats the case, I think thats enough evidence to make an own answer for you ;)

Comment: @Zaibis I've never been to Disneyland myself (and thus never took a ride on their Railroad) but from the [wiki](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Disneyland_Railroad#Trivia) I'd guess his narration comes off-stage

Comment: @Zaibis, I thought FST NML was Flash's racing car, which has no relation to the other plate.